# do a php check for certain data in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use the if function (or something familiar) to check for certain data in a certain field(s), in certain rows...

so something like

```
include ('db_connection_data.php')

mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");

$select = mysql_query("SELECT my_field FROM your_table WHERE name = 'John' AND Unique_id = "54213568545145554542365647862")

while($my_var = mysql_fetch_array($select)) { $name = $my_var["name"]; $unique_id = $my_var["unique_id"]; }

//here's where i get lost...

    include ('sponsor_details.php')

if ($sponsor_name = $name AND $sponsor_id = $unique_id)
//if the info is correct in the database, carry on processing the rest of the script
```

that's about all I can think of and I know its probably wrong. I want php to check in the db if the data is correct (same as the data in 'sponsor_details.php'). If the data is correct, it can finish processing the rest of the script but if it's not, echo a short message explaining the situation to the user.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple things:

```
// you did not properly quote 54213568545145554542365647862
$select = mysql_query("SELECT my_field FROM your_table WHERE ".
             // add semi-colon
             "name = 'John' AND Unique_id = '54213568545145554542365647862'");

// no need for while($my_var = mysql_fetch_array($select)). Just do:
$my_var = mysql_fetch_array($select);
// note: these should be 'John' and 54213568545145554542365647862 
// (you hard-coded them into the query).
$name = $my_var["name"]; $unique_id = $my_var["unique_id"];

//You are using assignment when you probably mean equality test
// note '==' instead of '=', more on this below
if ($sponsor_name == $name AND $sponsor_id == $unique_id)
```

PHP has three uses of '='. One means assignment $a = $b sets $a to the value of $b. The second is "loose equality": $a == $b means that $a is equal to $b, but this will also return TRUE for things like TRUE == 1, FALSE == NULL, and (most dastardly) 0 == FALSE. The final meaning is strict equality -- while "loose equality" returns true for 0 == FALSE, it returns FALSE for 0 === FALSE.

The way you're using it in the conditional is equivalent to saying:

```
$sponsor_name = $name; $sponsor_id = $unique_id;
// NOTE: && means AND.
if( $sponsor_name && $sponsor_id )
// also could be: if( $name && $unique_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example code you are not comparing the values, you are assigning them.

Change this:

```
if ($sponsor_name = $name AND $sponsor_id = $unique_id)
```

To compare:

```
if ($sponsor_name == $name AND $sponsor_id == $unique_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

if data which you will compare to db come from sponsor_details.php you should include it before select statement.